# Experience developing w/ TypeScript in VS2017 is not the same as VSCode

Tags: angular, ide, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2017

Developing an Angular 2/4 app in VSCode is so much easier than in VS2017. Is there an extension that I might be missing? The intellisense is way better in VSCode, in VS2017 I have a bunch of red squigglys. Additionally, the coloring of the TypeScript code is way better.

Before I fully switch to VSCode for my client apps I wanted to see if there might be a solution to getting the same look and feel so I can keep everything in one place.

Comment: did you install all the packages related to typescript and angular development in vs2017?

Comment: @Aravind packages from the new VS installer or Extensions?

Comment: Vs installer. . .

Comment: You're probably missing d.ts files for the libraries you're consuming in VS. Are they a part of your project?

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking for ways to bring the same angular experience to VS2017. Well, responsible for a lot of that is the "angular language service" that is only coming to VS in version 15.5:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2017/10/24/visual-studio-2017-version-15-5-preview-2